# Powershell .count function not working as expected

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get a list of all scheduled tasks on a server within a certian path that don't have a `LastTaskResult` of '0'. Just displaying all failures.

Simple bit of code I thought but it's not returning as expected, my code is:

```
$var = Get-ScheduledTask | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | select * | where {$_.TaskPath -eq "\"} 
$var = $var | select * | where {$_.LastTaskResult -ne 0}
$var.count
```

If I remove the second line I can see that there is one value returned but the count is returning nothing (not even 0)

If I run the same but using -eq then it gives me a count of 2 which is correct, anyone come across this issue before?

I've had a look around but I can;t see anything.

(Just a note, I'm very new to Powershell)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are correct, `Count` is not always reliable for every situation. Especially not in the older versions of PowerShell.

Please use the following CmdLet:

```
$var | Measure-Object
```

This can be enhanced to:

```
if (($var | Measure-Object).Count -ne 0) {
    'We found stuff'
}
```

More information on this CmdLet can be found when typing:

```
Get-Help Measure-Command -ShowWindow
```

As in the answer of @Lieven, you can also force your result to be an `Array`:

```
@($var).count
$var = @(Get-Process | Select-Object -First 0); $var.count
```

Comment: Perfect, who would have thought that .count wouldn't be very good at counting! Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome Will, keep exploring. The more you play with PowerShell the more fun it gets :)

Comment: This resolved the same issue for me. Anyone have any resources as to why ().count returns 0 in some cases. NVM, the result blow says it all ha ha

Answer (score 7):

When the pipe is returning a single result, `$var` becomes a `PSCustomObject`. A `PSCustomObject` doesn't have a count. When it's returning multiple results, you get an **array** of `PSCustomObjects` and you can use a count.

You can use `GetType()` to determine the resulting type like this

`($var | select * | where {$_.LastTaskResult -ne 0}).GetType()`

Now the easiest solution I know of to resolve this is by explicitly setting the type of the variable as such

```
$var = Get-ScheduledTask | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | select * | where {$_.TaskPath -eq "\"} 
[PSCustomObject[]]$var = $var | select * | where {$_.LastTaskResult -ne 0}
$var.count
```

Comment: This is a little unrelated question but I 'd like to ask you one. Is `count` a function or method or property? When listed via `get-member`, there is no `count` in the list.

Comment: @SmartHumanism - Good question. The `$var | get-member` returns the member of the *items* in the array so that's not what you want. I know that the `[System.Array]` type has a count property but I have no idea how to make that visible through Get-Member.

Answer (score 6):

If you strongly type your variable in advance you can avoid this.

**PS C:> [array]$var = @()**

PS C:> $var = Get-ScheduledTask | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | select * | where {$_.TaskPath -eq "\"}

PS C:> $var = $var | select * | where {$_.LastTaskResult -ne 0}

PS C:> $var.count

1

This will ensure that $var is always an array and won't get changed by PS.

Answer (score 1):

I find that if I declare the array as an empty array and then add items to it (+=)instead of assigning a result to it the count works.

```
$servers = @()

$Servers += Get-ADComputer -Server $domain -Filter {samaccountname -eq 'OneServer01$'} `
  -SearchBase $serverOU -SearchScope Subtree  | Select Name, DistinguishedName
```

`$Servers.Count` will now display as 1 where simply using `=` does not display anything at all as is seen as a `PSCustomObject` and not a collection.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thanks for answering. However, please put code in code boxes and not in normal text.

Answer (score -1):

```
([object[]]$var).Count


@( ([psobject] $null), (New-Object psobject), (1..2 | % {New-Object psobject}) ) `
| % {"$( $_.Count ) : $( ([object[]]$_).Count )"}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. Please take the [tour] and see [answer].

Comment: Also, some decend formatting and indentation would improve the readability.

Comment: @Chris & @LaurenzAlbe.

@WillRyan wrote that it doesn't work
`$var.count`.

The answer is one line of code
`([object[]]$var).Count`.
It doesn't require decend formatting and indentation.


The rest of the evil one.